# Embedded Fonts in Skins

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have been using a swc embedded font throughout my application and it has worked fine. I am now attempting to use the same font in a custom skin and a custom item renderer, both within the same project, by setting the font-family attribute to the same font name I have been using throughout. I am able to set the family to device fonts and see the change, though not with the embedded font. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Here is the label:

```
<s:Label id="labelDisplay" fontFamily="{Constants.HELVETICA_ULTRALIGHT}" maxDisplayedLines="1"  mouseEnabled="false" mouseChildren="false" right="32" minWidth="75" fontSize="25" color="{Constants.COLOR_DARK_PINK}" verticalCenter="2"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: @user431244: bring your some of your code man!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I switched from embedding the fonts with a swc and used css. This took care of my issues, aside from 2 of the 3 fonts didn't work until I changed embedAsCFF to false which is odd because I'm only using the fonts in spark components. Oh well, works now.

Thanks!